# I create PHP game and i need get variable to URL

Tags: php, string, variables, url

I have created `PHP` game and i don't know how to add variable to URL.. i try this

```
<?php
if($_GET["heroldhp"]<"1") {
  header("Location: win.php?enemy=Herold&name=<?php echo $name; ?>&narod=<?php echo $narod; ?>");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<?php` and `?>` tags like below:-

```
<?php
if($_GET["heroldhp"]<"1") {
  header("Location: win.php?enemy=Herold&name=$name&narod=$narod");
  exit;
}
?>
```

***Note:-*** Make sure that `$name,$narod` is created and have some value before `header(...)` code otherwise it will raise issue on `win.php` page.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
<?php
if($_GET["heroldhp"]<"1") {
  header("Location: win.php?enemy=Herold&name=" .$name . "&narod=" . $narod);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 if($_GET["heroldhp"]<"1") {
   header("Location: win.php?enemy=Herold&name=$name&narod=$narod");
   exit;
 }
?>
```

you are already with in your php so why you use php start tag with in header(); above is the right way to do your code